# extract file from linux bootable disk

Tags: linux, storage, disk, data-recovery

I have a bootable IDE hard drive which has Linux on it(with GRUB bootloader).
I need to extract files inside this hard drive, but the problem is the booting fails
because of some reason... super-block or boot sector must be corrupted. (the hard drive uses EXT3 partition)

So I am trying to mount my corrupted hard drive into another system and extract data from there. however, if I mount my corrupted hard drive, the fdisk -l tells me that "Disk /dev/sdb doesn't contain a valid partition table"

In the worst case, I want to recover even some partial data off from this disk. what would be the best way to do this??  Thank you in advance.

Comment: Couple of weeks back, after attempting nearly everything you wrote, I bought a 2.5" hdd case, put my laptop HDD in that and extracted data. This ofcourse makes the problem less interesting.

Answer (score -1):

You can run any linux live CD/DVD and then you can be able to get required files

If you want to fix boot sector then refer this [link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BootSectorFix)